# Tags for the Toaru-verse (no, the other one)

Tags: discussion, tags, lumping-and-splitting

Do we want separate tags for [Toaru Hikuushi e no Tsuioku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Princess_and_the_Pilot) (*The Princess and the Pilot*) and [Toaru Hikuushi e no Koiuta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pilot%27s_Love_Song) (*The Pilot's Love Song*)?

I haven't seen/read Tsuioku, but it seems like we might have a situation where these are two separate series set in the same universe, which happen to intersect one another sometimes, in which case the Railgun/Index precedent suggests that we should introduce a separate tag for Tsuioku (probably `princess-and-the-pilot`, since adding a `the-` at the beginning of that takes it over 25 characters).

(I ask because [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8104/is-charles-the-pilot-of-the-seagull-plane) could use a tag for Tsuioku if in fact we want such a thing.)

Comment: Think Fma is pretty much the same right, currently using only 1 tag for all the different ones. Even thou some are totaly differnt.